# Don't understand proof that interior of a set is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Say we want to show that the interior of a set $A$ is open.

If $x \in Int(A)$, then there exists an open ball $B_r(x) \subseteq A$.

Since $B_r(x)$ is open, $y \in B_r(x)$ also has an open ball $B_s(y) \subseteq B_r(x) \subseteq A$, so $y \in Int(A)$.

Now, somehow we have to show that the ball $B_r(x) \subseteq Int(A)$, and that would complete the proof.

All of the proofs I read say this is obvious, but I don't see how $B_r(x) \subseteq Int(A)$ immediately follows here.

Comment: You have, for an _arbitrary_ $y\in B_r(x)$, shown that there is a ball $B_s(y)$ contained in $A$ and hence $y\in \operatorname{Int} A$. That means _for all_ $y\in B_r(x)$ you have $y\in \operatorname{Int} A$, and that's by definition $B_r(x) \subseteq \operatorname{Int} A$.

Comment: You just showed that $y \in B_r(x) \implies y \in Int(A)$. So $B_r(x)\subseteq Int(A)$

Comment: Are you saying the argument is circular?  @Daniel Fischer

Comment: @Plotinus No, I don't think Daniel Fischer is saying the OP's argument is circular. Rather , I believe Daniel is bringing attention to the fact that the $y$ in $y\in B_r(x)$ can be chosen arbitrarily, and thus the OP showed, without realizing, that $ \forall y  \left( y \in B_r(x) \implies y \in Int(A)\right) $. This is equivalent to $B_r(x)\subseteq Int(A)$, by definition of subset , viz., $A \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in A \implies x \in B)$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\text{Int}(A)=\{x\in X\mid \exists r>0: B_r(x)\subset A\}.$$

Therefore
$$\forall x\in \text{Int}(A), \exists r_x>0: B_r(x)\subset A,$$
and thus 
$$\text{Int}(A)=\bigcup_{x\in \text{Int}A}B_{r_x}(x).$$

We finally conclude that $\text{Int}(A)$ is open.

Comment: How does $x \in \text{Int}(A), B_r(x) \subset A$ imply $$\text{Int}(A) = \bigcup_{x\in\text{Int}(A)} B_r(x)$$ ?

Comment: @feynhat well as $B_r(x)$ is open, we have $B_r(x)\subset int(A)$ and so $int(A) = \cup_{x\in int(A)} x\subset \cup_{x\in int(A)} B_r(x) \subset int(A)$.

Comment: All in one def:Int(A)=$\bigcup$ {U $\subset$ X : U is open and U $\subset$ A }

Answer (score -1):

If $ x \in int(E) $ then $ \exists r >0 $ , $ B_r(x) \subset E $

Now $ \forall y \in B_r(x) \subset E $, $ \exists r_y = r - d(x,y) $, $ \ni B_{r_y} \subset B_r (x) \subset E $ Hence $ y \in int(E) $

Hence $ B_r(x) \subset int(E) $ or x is interior point of int(E)

Comment: I don't understand why did I get 2 negative votes, I am incorrect please tell me where!