# The interior of interior of a set is its interior

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $ (X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. How can I show that $(A^\circ)^\circ = A^\circ $?
$A^\circ$ denotes the set of all interior points of $A$.

---

I know that $x \in A$ is interior if there exists an $ r>0$ such that $B_r(x) \subset A$ .  So i think to try to prove that $(A ^\circ)^\circ \subset A^\circ$ and $A^\circ \subset (A^\circ)^\circ$ , but I cannot think how to start.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Do you know the definition of the interior of a set?

Comment: I know that $x \in A$ is interior if there exists an $ r>0$ such that $B_r(x) \in A$ .  So i think to try to prove that $(A ^\circ)^\circ \subset A^\circ$ and $A^\circ \subset (A^\circ)^\circ$ , but I cannot think how to start.

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Which sets $B$ have the property that $B^\circ = B$, meaning every point is interior to them? They have a name: *open* sets.

So, you are asking how to prove that the interior of any set is an open set. Luckily, [this was done before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1164877).